# Handling list index out of range when using Zip for lists in python

Tags: python, list, zip

Normally I could use the following code to print out into one statement about cats like so:

```
cats = ["ronny", "brodie", "fraise", "luke"]
age = [5, 6, 7, 11]
cats_by_age = sorted(zip(age, cats))

print("The age of the oldest cat is {}. This cat is {}".format(*cats_by_age[-1]))
print("The age of the youngest cat is {}. This cat is {}".format(*cats_by_age[0]))
```

However if I wanted to have user input for the lists, and the list become i.e.

```
cats = ["ronny"]
age = [5]
cats_by_age = sorted(zip(age, cats))
print("The age of the oldest cat is {}. This cat is {}".format(*cats_by_age[-1]))
print("The age of the youngest cat is {}. This cat is {}".format(*cats_by_age[0]))
```

This would then give me the error: "list index out of range". How Do I handle this error?

Comment: your second example doesn't contain a `cats_by_age` list at all.

Comment: You have invalid string literals in your code; only triple-quoted strings can span multiple lines.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're literally asking how to catch exceptions?

Comment: I don't see why your second code wouldn't work like the first one, granted you fix the syntax (line breaks) and include the `cats_by_age = sorted(zip(age, cats))`...